# Number of 7-digit numbers in the form abcdcba and average of such

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

(i) How many 7-digit numbers are in the form of abcdcba   (symmetric about the digit in the middle)?

(ii) What is the average of such numbers?

I manage to answer the first question correctly. I treated the first part as how many unique integers are there between 1000 and 9999 inclusive. Which is 9*9*8*7 = 4536. 
I have no idea on the second part. I don't think there exist a close form solution to sum up a range of unique integers.

Comment: Do a,b,c,d need to be distinct, or is `1111111` a valid example?

Comment: A broad hint for (ii) regardless of the answer: Note that the average over all $i$ of $(10\times a_i+b_i)$ is $10\times$ the average (over all $i$) of $a_i$ plus the average of $b_i$ (why?).

Comment: They all have to be unique

Comment: Hint: $E(a) = ?$, etc.  Then use linearity of expectation (which fortunately doesn't require the variables to be independent).  Though in calculating $E(b)$, I think 1 through 9 are slightly less probable than 0 so you would need to take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and last digits range uniformly from $1$ to $9$, so average $5$.  Having chosen the first digit the second has to be different.  It is the average of the digits that are left, which is the same as the average of all the digits except $5$.  That is $\frac 19 \cdot 40 = \frac {40}9$  We could have picked any digit next after the first, so the average of each digit is $\frac {40}9$.  The average number is then $5(10^6+1)+\frac {40}9(10^5+10^4+10^3+10^2+10)$

Answer (score 0):

(this is  a verification only, do not treat this as a solution)

For (i) I think your solution is correct. I think a better way would be to separate the number into two cases.

Since the last $3$ digits $cba$ depend on the first $3$ $abc$, then we calculate $9*9*8$. This is because the first digit cannot be $0$, hence leaving $9$ choices left. Also, the second digit has $(9-1) + 1$ choices removing the last digit chosen but adding $0$ into the number of choices.

The last step is to add the case for the last digit $d$. There are (8-1) choices left for $d$, so the number of cases is $9*9*8*7$ which is $4536$ as you correctly answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Then $a$ can be any element of $S\setminus \{0\}$. $b$ can be any element of $S\setminus\{a\}$. $c$ can be any element of $S\setminus\{a,b\}$. $d$ can be any element of $S\setminus\{a,b,c\}$. So, there are $9\times9\times8\times 7=4536$ possible numbers.

We have

$$E[a]=\sum_{i=1}^9\left(\frac{1}{9}\times i\right)=5$$

Since $\displaystyle P(b=0)=\frac{1}{9}$, $\displaystyle P(b=i)=\frac{1}{9}\times \left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)$ for $i=1,2,\dots,0$.

$$E[b]=\frac{1}{9}\times 0+\sum_{i=1}^9\left[\frac{1}{9}\left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)\times i\right]=\frac{40}{9}$$

We also have $\displaystyle P(c=0)=\frac{8}{9}\times \frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{9}$ and $\displaystyle P(d=0)=\frac{8}{9}\times \frac{7}{8}\times \frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{9}$. So,

$$E[c]=E[d]=\frac{40}{9}$$

The average of the numbers is

$$1000001E[a]+100010E[b]+10100E[c]+1000E[d]=\frac{49444445}{9}=5493827\frac{2}{9}$$

---

This problem can also be solved by brute force.

The sum of the numbers is

\begin{align}
&\;\sum_{a\in S\setminus \{0\}}\sum_{b\in S\setminus\{a\}}\sum_{c\in S\setminus\{a,b\}}\sum_{d\in S\setminus\{a,b,c\}}(1000001a+100010b+10100c+1000d)\\
=&\;\sum_{a\in S\setminus \{0\}}\sum_{b\in S\setminus\{a\}}\sum_{c\in S\setminus\{a,b\}}\left[7(1000001a+100010b+10100c)+1000\left(\sum_{i=0}^9i-a-b-c\right)\right]\\
=&\;\sum_{a\in S\setminus \{0\}}\sum_{b\in S\setminus\{a\}}\sum_{c\in S\setminus\{a,b\}}\left(6999007a+699070b+69700c+45000\right)\\
=&\;\sum_{a\in S\setminus \{0\}}\sum_{b\in S\setminus\{a\}}\left[8(6999007a+699070b+45000)+69700\left(\sum_{j=0}^9j-a-b\right)\right]\\
=&\;\sum_{a\in S\setminus \{0\}}\sum_{b\in S\setminus\{a\}}\left(55922356a+5522860b+3496500\right)\\
=&\;\sum_{a\in S\setminus \{0\}}\left[9(55922356a+3496500)+5522860\left(\sum_{k=0}^9k-a\right)\right]\\
=&\;\sum_{a\in S\setminus \{0\}}\left(497778344a+279997200)\right)\\
=&\;497778344\sum_{a=1}^9a+9(279997200)\\
=&\;24920000280
\end{align}

The average of the numbers is

$$\frac{24920000280}{4536}=\frac{49444445}{9}=5493827\frac{2}{9}$$